# Password for iis after installing

Tags: windows, iis, installation

After installing IIS on my dev system, window xp professional, its asking for username and password while trying to access http://localhost. Can you please help me out. Tried googling and tried may things but could not resolve the issue.

1. Anonymous access is enabled
2. iusr_ is given full access to the wwwroot folder
3. asp.net2.0 has been registered

etc. But still not working. :(

**EDIT:**
Now the password issue has gone off and shows this:
Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A0046)
Permission denied: 'GetObject'
/localstart.asp, line 40

Browser Type:
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

Page:
GET /localstart.asp

Comment: Just a tought: are you sure it's actually IIS which is answering your request? Maybe some other process bound to port 80 before it, and it wasn't even able to start.

Comment: Initially there was this problem and iis would not start and on running netstat on the cmd prompt, found out that skype was using my 80 port. Have fixed it and verified that IIS is using the port.

Comment: Ok. You said the IUSR_MachineName account has full control over wwwroot: it's the website root actually pointing there? And it's the website anonymous user account actually IUSR_MachineName?

Comment: Yes. This problem arises on browsing the Default website. It calls the iisstart.asp and in turn the localstart.asp file.

Comment: Can you view a simple, static web page (.htm)? Maybe the problem is related to the ASP interpreter.

Comment: Have tried putting a asp, html, htm and aspx files under the wwwroot folder. With just a 'hello' text. All these gets displayed while accessing <code>localhost/test.asp</code>; etc. its just that 'localhost' does not work it asks for a username and password

Comment: What happens when you authenticate with your username/password? Do you get the resource? Or does IIS continue to ask for credentials?

Comment: I was not sure which username to give. I tried giving the one with which i log on to my system. it has admin rights. But was continuing to for credentials.

Comment: If this computer is in a Windows domain, try DOMAIN\Username as username.

Answer (score 1):

Another try: is there a web.config file in wwwroot (or in a parent folder)? If yes, check if authentication is explicitly defined:

```
 <system.web>
     ...
     <authentication mode="Windows"/>
     ...
```

See: [How To: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998358.aspx) (MSDN)

Comment: There is no web.config file. It just has the default IIS files. The ones that come in the wwwroot folder when you install IIS. The localstart.asp and iisstart.asp etc files for the Default website.

Answer (score 0):

Put a simple test.html (create it there, don't copy from another location) in the wwwroot folder and try to access it.

Check, if the permissions you assigned to wwwroot propageted to the single files in that folder (right-click, Security-tab etc.).

Do you use a virtual directory which points to a different folder which you didn't assign the permissions?

Comment: Have tried putting a asp, html, htm and aspx files under the wwwroot folder. With just a 'hello' text. All these gets displayed while accessing <code>http://localhost/test.asp</code> etc. its just that 'http://localhost/' does not work it asks for a username and password.

Comment: what happens if you explicitly call localhost/iisstart.asp or localhost/localstart.asp?

Comment: Its the same it asks for the username and password. With both IE and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using http://localhost, can you use http://pcname, where pcname is whatever your computer name is.

If you're using Firefox try it with IE instead.

Also try this method (from http://www.msfn.org/board/lofiversion/index.php/t33489.html):

- Click Start>Administrative Tools>Internet Information Services
- Expand the left tree, right-click your WebSite>Properties
- Click on Directory Security, then in "Anonymous access and authentication control" click on Edit
- Tick "Allow IIS to control password", then OK and come out of IIS.

Comment: The "Allow IIS to control password" is ticked. Its the same while trying with pcname or 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.xx it asks for username/password.

Comment: But what about the actual computer name (System properties | Computer name | Full computer name) or browser?

Comment: i have tried it with my computer name and browser on both IE and firefox it was the same. But now the passoword problem has gone. i get a different message have edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running on Windows XP Professional, I would try turning off simple file sharing.  To access simple file sharing go to Windows Explorer-->Tools-->Folder Options-->View-->all the way down at the bottom there will be an option for simple file sharing.  To turn it off uncheck the box.

Comment: How could this possibly help? Blindly throwing crap at the wall and hoping something sticks isn't how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

The version of IIS (PWS) included in XP and versions since has a backdoor capable of revealing the plaintext password of the IIS user accounts.

You can expose the password for the anonymous user account and plug it into the pesky UserID/Password prompt in your troubleshooting process.
One of many tools capable of revealing this password and one I've chosen based on its reliability is IISPWDS.exe (hosted by the author at http://www.chambet.com/iismetabase.html).

But like most free security tools, downloading it and using it will anger your antivirus.

For a period of time, Microsoft quietly provided the ability to view the password using a version of their MetaEditor or IIS Resource Kit for Windows Server 2003, it doesn't offend Antivirus programs if you require something so genteel.

The advice of others to check your directory perms is sound along with avoiding modification of the wwwroot directories, even the basic WebServer parameters unless you're fluent in web server administration (which CLEARLY YOU AREN'T based on your platform choices).

You're in dire need of patching your dev unit with at least the latest service pack to ameliorate the phonebook thick list of browser, web server and especially scripting issues included with every Microsoft product that barely conforms to common industry standards and communication protocols.

Or, become accustomed to struggling every inch of every day when attempting to use your XP dev WebServer in the manner you've described.